# angular2 missing query string in HashLocationStrategy

Tags: angular

when I use PathLocationStrategy, 
http://localhost:3000/dashboard/123?cc=1111   works fine.

when I use HashLocationStrategy, visit http://localhost:3000/?cc=1111#/dashboard/123
the url always redirect to  http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard/123, and miss the query string `?cc=1111`

my demo code repo https://github.com/jinceon/routebug

### ==========updated===========

I know my mistake now.

the url I visit is http://localhost:3000/?cc=1111#/dashboard/123

@GünterZöchbauer

thanks very much

the right url is http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard/123?cc=1111

### ----my another question------

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
]
```

when I visit http://localhost:3000/#/?cc=1111, I thought it will redirect to http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard?cc=1111, but it in fact redirect to http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard.

http://localhost:3000/?cc=1111

http://localhost:3000/#/?cc=1111

http://localhost:3000/?cc=1111#/
???

Comment: I'm sure this normally just works. Please provide more information about your configuration (routes, redirects, guards, ....)

Comment: https://github.com/jinceon/routebug

Comment: The project doesn't have an `apples` route. What happens when you navigate to `http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard/123?cc=1111` or  `http://localhost:3000/index.html/#/dashboard/123?cc=1111`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks very much. I know my mistake now.

Answer (score 0):

I know my mistake now.

the url I visit is http://localhost:3000/?cc=1111#/dashboard/123

@GünterZöchbauer

thanks very much

the right url is 
http://localhost:3000/#/dashboard/123?cc=1111