# HashLocationStrategy expected URL with query behavior

Tags: angular

What is the expected behavior in Angular 2+ for query parameters on a URL when using HashLocationStrategy?  Currently I see that query parameters are dropped (in the browser URL and ActivatedRoute) when the parameters are supplied before the `#/route`.

Unfortunately I cannot locate any official documentation stating the expected behavior.  However, I do understand that client-side routing is only supposed to detect anything which comes after the `#` and nothing before that (please correct me if I'm wrong about that).

From what I can tell, the query string is expected to occur after the `#/route`, for example something like `base_path#/route?key=value` works fine.  I can see that the query string is retained in the browser URL as well as the ActivatedRoute for my component.  However, I'm expecting to be able to put the query string before the `#` as well, like documented at https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/url.html#url_url_strings_and_url_objects

Perhaps I'm mixing two different concepts.  Is Angular hash routing different than fragments that may appear after `#` from the Node.js link above?

I did find a useful and somewhat similar post,  [HashLocationStrategy and query parameters in angular 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46396572/hashlocationstrategy-and-query-parameters-in-angular-4), in which I can provide a workaround solution by detecting the query string before the `#` using a PathLocationStrategy provider and then moving that query string on to the end of the URL and forcing a redirect to that URL with appended query string (using `Router.navigateByUrl`).  But I don't want to go into the trouble of providing that as a solution if I can rule it as an unexpected HashLocationStrategy URL.

Here's the workaround code that I mention aboved, placed in the root component

```
export class RootComponent {
  constructor(
    router: Router,
    pathLocationStrategy: PathLocationStrategy) {
    const basePath = pathLocationStrategy.getBaseHref();
    console.log('basePath: ', basePath);
    const absolutePathWithParams = pathLocationStrategy.path();
    console.log('absolutePathWithParams: ', absolutePathWithParams);

    const hashPath = window.location.hash;
    if (hashPath.length > 0 && basePath !== absolutePathWithParams) {
      console.log('navigateByUrl: ', absolutePathWithParams);
      console.log('window.location.hash', window.location.hash);
      router.navigateByUrl(hashPath.substr(1) + absolutePathWithParams.replace(basePath, ''));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Here's another post that seems to lean towards the idea that query params should come after the `#/route`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42245754/angular2-missing-query-string-in-hashlocationstrategy
But there's no supporting documentation attached to the "answer" to give me the warm and fuzzy that it's 100% accurate.

Comment: The HashLocationStrategy doc says: *A LocationStrategy used to configure the Location service to represent its state in the hash fragment of the browser's URL.* So, the state is stored in the hash fragment. And since the query params are part of the state... Anyway, doesn't your experiment clear any doubt you might have?

Comment: Thanks!  Yes, there does seem to be much evidence to conclude that query params must be a part of the hash fragment while using HashLocationStrategy.

Even browsing to a route using `<a [routerLink]="['/myroute']" [queryParams]="{key:value}">Go to route</a>` will append the query string to the end of the hash route.

I guess I was just looking for exact doc or feedback that specifically states the URL format to be: `http://<base_url>:<port>#/path?queryString`.  The testing seems to prove this, but a direct statement in the doc would really help to clear up the doubt.

Comment: But it's funny... the limited doc for HashLocationStrategy contains a "hash fragment" link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax which clearly diagrams that the hash fragment should come after the query string in the URL.  So again, this leans me towards doubting that the behavior for Angular's HashLocationStrategy for query strings is correct nor consistent.
It sure makes it difficult for my JS library, which takes URLs as input, to understand and support both formats (Angular's and then everyone elses).

Comment: That's the point of the hash strategy: storing everything that should normally be before the hash after it: the path and the query string. The whole point is to be able to just drop an index.html file on a dumb server, and to still be able to navigate, change the URL, and refresh without losing the current page. And without having to use the pushState API, in case the browser is really old and doesn't support it.

Comment: Thank you for your help!  I believe for my library I'll need to take an approach of sending parameters without the use of a query string (or really, in addition to the query string as to not break backwards compatibility).  This is the only way in which I believe my JS library can handle both types of URLs and still get the information it needs.